# How to initialize mesibo console in reactjs. for web app and not android apps. In reactJS not in Reactnative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, mesibo

**How can I initialize mesibo connection in my reactjs web app with django backend.** 
I dont find any resources of doing that. even though i have included 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.mesibo.com/mesibo.js"></script>` 
in index.html and its loading in browser as well but having initialized the

```
initializeApiConn = () => {
  this.setState({
    api: new Mesibo()
  })
}
```

its not recognizing *Mesibo()* 
can i have any resources and any links to understand this connection of mesibo with reactjs.

--------------------------------- 
**EDIT:**

- I have included mesibo js in `<head>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are including mesibo js your index.html, you may need to use window.Mesibo() in ReactJS

Alternatively, use DOM method to load mesibo.

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://api.mesibo.com/mesibo.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```